# LDAP the right choice?

Tags: ssh, ldap, openldap

So I'm looking for a solution for ssh key authorisation access to numerous servers, and have been pointed towards using LDAP. I wanted to present the use case and see if LDAP would be applicable and any suggestions or help would be appropriated.

Would it be possible to use LDAP to restrict access to specific servers per user/group using ssh keys. So a user tries to access a box which would bounce out to the LDAP server with the server and user details. This would then check if that person has access to that server and potentially return the correlating key to grant access.

After some research it seems possible to do the above, but I couldn't find anywhere where its for specific servers.

Also is openLDAP the best to use, I've tried setting this up and run into several issues like checksum on config files etc.

Answer (score 0):

> So a user tries to access a box which would bounce out to the LDAP server with the server and user details. This would then check if that person has access to that server

Yes and no. The purpose of an LDAP server is to store information, not to perform arbitrary checks. (It's just a database.)

So you can achieve this, but actual authorization checks will be done sshd-side (the service itself decides whether to accept users or not). For Linux, this will usually happen inside the PAM module belonging to the LDAP client software (either nslcd or sssd).

> and potentially return the correlating key to grant access.

Note the difference between authentication and authorization. The former verifies who the user is; the latter verifies what the user is allowed to do.

So while it is *possible* to configure the LDAP software so that it doesn't return any keys (because it already knows that the user will be denied later), that's not how LDAP clients work by default, and it might be more difficult to implement.

Instead, it is normal that the LDAP server would *always* return the SSH keys the sshd would accept them during the authentication phase – because if the user is not allowed to *use* the server, they will be rejected in the authorization phase anyway.

The latter method has the advantage of working equally well regardless of the authentication mechanism. Whether the user authenticates using a password, a SSH key, or a smartcard, or a Kerberos token, they will be rejected (or accepted) all the same.

> After some research it seems possible to do the above, but I couldn't find anywhere where its for specific servers.

As mentioned above, it may be easier to separate key retrieval from authorization.

1. Configure LDAP client software (SSSD or nslcd) to retrieve user information from the directory, and to check authorization using some rules. (The most traditional method is to use `host:` attributes on user accounts.)

   Test whether SSSD's pam_sss (or nslcd's pam_ldap) correctly checks privileges, using `pamtester sshd Someusername acct_mgmt`.
2. Configure an `AuthorizedKeysCommand` in sshd_config to retrieve the keys from LDAP. If you chose SSSD earlier, it has a built-in helper program for this; otherwise you might have to write your own.

> run into several issues like checksum on config files etc.

OpenLDAP has two config formats:

- A simple text file `slapd.conf`, which is editable directly and **doesn't** have checksums.
- The LDAP-based `cn=config`, which – despite being stored on disk in the form of LDIF textfiles – is not meant to be edited directly. Once you build a cn=config, you are supposed to do *all* editing via LDAP itself (or via `slapadd` if necessary).

You found checksums when you were looking at the 2nd variant. I can only assume they're there as a deterrent against direct editing (it's not impossible but *should not* be done except in emergencies).

Comment: My [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com), based on OpenLDAP, has ACLs which prohibit access to the SSH key stored in the user's entry in case there is no valid [login relationship](https://www.ae-dir.com/docs.html#eer) between a service/host and a user (indirect via group memberships).

Answer (score 0):

LDAP administers many aspects of the network, and can also be set to store SSH
public keys. This requires that the SSH client be configured to query LDAP
for the required information.

You will find instructions on setting this up in the Server Fault article
[SSH key authentication using LDAP](https://serverfault.com/questions/653792/ssh-key-authentication-using-ldap) as regarding:

- Update LDAP to include the OpenSSH-LPK schema
- Create a script that queries LDAP for a user's public key
- Update `sshd_config` to point to the script from the previous step

LDAP in this case functions only as a database with access controls.
You may achieve similar results without LDAP with various other types of products,
ranging from corporate firewalls to sophisticated administration offering
single sign-on solutions.

If you would like to use other products than LDAP, the list is very long.
I would advise using the services of a company or consultant that works
in the area of network security. The right solution for you depends
on many factors, such as your geographical location, available equipment,
and not forgetting budget.